# Picking up AWS credentials under IAM role running sbt test

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I've written a Spark Scala test and I'm trying to run it on an EC2 instance that has the proper IAM role to access s3.
I say this because I can run spark-submit and execute Spark jon without any issues.

However, when I try to execute my test by calling

```
sbt test
```

I obtain the following error

```
com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from 
any provider in the chain
at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials(AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:117)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3521)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.headBucket(AmazonS3Client.java:1031)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.doesBucketExist(AmazonS3Client.java:994)
```

Can you advise as to what I'm missing ? I'm not as familiar with the workings of Spark on EMR and IAM/S3 to decipher what I'm missing,

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that all I needed were the following settings in the build.sbt to properly use the assumed IAM role and access s3a with no problems on Spark 2.4.0 using `sbt test`:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "2.8.5"
libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-core" % "1.11.479"
libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-s3" % "1.11.479"
libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-kms" % "1.11.479"
```

Comment: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#Features

Comment: you should know that hadoop-aws was compiled against aws-sdk 1.10.6 and the AWS SDKs have proven *very* backwards-incompatible; If you get failures here switch to that version. And if you do stay with the 1.11.x line, the shaded aws-sdk-bundle isolates you from jackson version hell.  See https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws/2.8.5

Answer (score 0):

You need to set AWS credentials to connect to S3 from Spark.

They can be defined at runtime as well:

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.access.key", <ACCESS_KEY>)
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", <SECRET_KEY>)
```

Or from environment variables:

```
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<ACCESS_KEY>
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<SECRET_KEY>
```

Comment: Since the EC2 instance assumes the correct IAM role, I don't have to do this when I call spark-submit. I'm wondering how I can obtain the same behavior when calling `sbt test`.